# Google Apps Script - Count files that are inside a worksheet subfolder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble creating a script in Google Apps Script that checks the number of files in a subfolder of the spreadsheet folder.

[image]

A friend here on the forum helped me to create a script that checks the spreadsheet folder, but now I need to modify it to check the subfolder of the spreadsheet folder.

The script I have at the moment is this one:

```
/** Written by Tanaike */ 
function CheckForFiles() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // This is your active Spreadsheet.
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
      if (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
        const files = parentFolder.next().getFiles();
        let count = 0;
        while (files.hasNext()) {
          const file = files.next();
          // console.log(file.getName()); // When you use this line, you can see the filename of the files.
          count++;
        }
        if (count >= 3) {
          throw new Error("Your expected error.");
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error("Spreadsheet has no parent folder.");
      }
    }
```

**Important point:** note that the spreadsheet folder is a template folder, that is, it will be duplicated and its name will be changed several times, for this reason I need the script to be something like "Check how many files there are inside the subfolder `FolderToBeCheck` which is inside the folder of this worksheet, if the number of files is more than 3, return an error"

How can I achieve this?

[Test Folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dn0XAHgiASpGgpPBvflhifeM1qw5Bn2T?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, from your showing image, it supposes that the folder name of the subfolder is `FolderToBeCheck`. In your question, it seems that the folder name is `FolderToBeChecked`. Please be careful about this difference.

```js
function CheckForFiles() {
  const subFolderName = "FolderToBeCheck"; // Please set your subfolder name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // This is your active Spreadsheet.
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  if (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
    const innerFolder = parentFolder.next().getFoldersByName(subFolderName); // <--- Modified
    if (innerFolder.hasNext()) {
      const files = innerFolder.next().getFiles();
      let count = 0;
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        const file = files.next();
        // console.log(file.getName()); // When you use this line, you can see the filename of the files.
        count++;
      }
      if (count >= 3) {
        throw new Error("Your expected error.");
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Folder of 'FolderToBeCheck' was not found.");
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("Spreadsheet has no parent folder.");
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the subfolder of `FolderToBeCheck` is checked. And, the number of files in the folder is counted.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made a mistake in writing, but I've edited the question to avoid future confusion.

It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help and attention!

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying. I could correctly understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: I just realized that the script checks the entire Drive for the `FolderToBeCheck` folder instead of just looking in the `FolderToBeCheck` folder that is inside the active Google Sheet folder. This is a problem because I will have several folders named `FolderToBeCheck` on my drive. How do I search only in the subfolder where the worksheet is?

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying.  I didn't notice it. I apologize for this. I updated the script, could you please confirm it again?

Comment: No way, you don't need to apologize, I'm learning a lot thanks to your patience and attention. The modification worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: @Tyrone Hirt Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.